# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, google-fonts

I am trying to use google fonts in my application and when I try to use as IBMPlexSans fonts I get this error...
'Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for embedded components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You probably forgot to export your component from the file it is defined in, or you may have mixed up default and named imports'.
Can anyone give me a hand ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppLoading } from 'expo'
import {
  useFonts,
  IBMPlexSans_100Thin,
  IBMPlexSans_100Thin_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_200ExtraLight,
  IBMPlexSans_200ExtraLight_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_300Light,
  IBMPlexSans_300Light_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_400Regular,
  IBMPlexSans_400Regular_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_500Medium,
  IBMPlexSans_500Medium_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_600SemiBold,
  IBMPlexSans_600SemiBold_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_700Bold,
  IBMPlexSans_700Bold_Italic,
} from '@expo-google-fonts/ibm-plex-sans';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Dimensions, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';




export default function RegisterScreen (props) {

    let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        IBMPlexSans_100Thin,
        IBMPlexSans_100Thin_Italic,
        IBMPlexSans_200ExtraLight,
        IBMPlexSans_200ExtraLight_Italic,
        IBMPlexSans_300Light,
        IBMPlexSans_300Light_Italic,
        IBMPlexSans_400Regular,
        IBMPlexSans_400Regular_Italic,
        IBMPlexSans_500Medium,
        IBMPlexSans_500Medium_Italic,
        IBMPlexSans_600SemiBold,
        IBMPlexSans_600SemiBold_Italic,
        IBMPlexSans_700Bold,
        IBMPlexSans_700Bold_Italic,
      });
     
      if (!fontsLoaded) {
        return <AppLoading />;
      }

    return (

        <View>
           <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'IBMPlexSans_100Thin' }}>Text Example</Text>
        </View>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/font-loading)

Firstly, install `expo-app-loading` like this

```
npm install expo-app-loading
```

then install `expo-font`

```
npm install expo-font
```

Create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located

Inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js`

Then your `useFonts.js` should look like this

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import {
  IBMPlexSans_100Thin,
  IBMPlexSans_100Thin_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_200ExtraLight,
  IBMPlexSans_200ExtraLight_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_300Light,
  IBMPlexSans_300Light_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_400Regular,
  IBMPlexSans_400Regular_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_500Medium,
  IBMPlexSans_500Medium_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_600SemiBold,
  IBMPlexSans_600SemiBold_Italic,
  IBMPlexSans_700Bold,
  IBMPlexSans_700Bold_Italic,
} from '@expo-google-fonts/ibm-plex-sans';

const useFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    IBMPlexSans_100Thin,
    IBMPlexSans_100Thin_Italic,
    IBMPlexSans_200ExtraLight,
    IBMPlexSans_200ExtraLight_Italic,
    IBMPlexSans_300Light,
    IBMPlexSans_300Light_Italic,
    IBMPlexSans_400Regular,
    IBMPlexSans_400Regular_Italic,
    IBMPlexSans_500Medium,
    IBMPlexSans_500Medium_Italic,
    IBMPlexSans_600SemiBold,
    IBMPlexSans_600SemiBold_Italic,
    IBMPlexSans_700Bold,
    IBMPlexSans_700Bold_Italic,
  });
};

export default useFonts;
```

And your `App.js` should look like this

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function RegisterScreen(props) {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFontsAndRestoreToken = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFontsAndRestoreToken}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'IBMPlexSans_100Thin' }}>Text Example</Text>
      <Text>Normal Text</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```